# Estoy intentando instalar React en mi VSC pero me sale este error

Tags: reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque me saldria este error, ya vi varios tutoriales y no me ayudan .

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.